# ngFor how to bind each element separately

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am trying to build one dashboard in Angular 4. In that dashboard I have used *ngFor to iterate over a json (coming via service) and have displayed a series of reports inside cards. In each card there are some icons on the header and after clicking them some actions will be performed.. such as refresh, download, pop-up info inside tooltip, pin-unpin etc.

To do this I thought of using variables to bind those elements like *(click)="function()"*, and also *[@animationTag]="variable"*, as below:

```
...
<div class="card" *ngFor="let r of reportCards; let x of index">
    <div class="card-header">
        {{r.reportName}}
        <div class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true" [@pinUnpin]="isPinned" (click)="unpinCard($event)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!ifMinimized" class="card-body">
       {{r.reportMainDesc}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!ifMinimized" class="card-footer">
       {{r.reportFooterDesc}}
    </div>
</div>
...
```

The corresponding animation code:

```
animations: [
trigger('pinUnpin', [
  state('pin', style({
      transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
  })),
  state('unpin', style({
      transform: 'rotate(90deg)',
  })),
  transition('pin => unpin', animate('300ms ease-in-out')),
  transition('unpin => pin', animate('300ms ease-in-out'))
]),
]
```

The corresponding function inside component:

```
unpinCard(pEvent) {
    this.ifMinimized = this.ifMinimized === true ? false : true;
    this.isPinned = this.isPinned === "pin" ? "unpin" : "pin";
}
```

**The Issue:**

All functions are working fine but the issue is whenever I am clicking one (pin) icon on a particular card.. the actions if performed upon all of the cards, means all cards are getting minimized together and also the (pin) icons of all cards are getting animated at same time.

I can guess that, this is due to the variables *ifMinimized* & *ifPinned* that are bound with all of the cards generated via ngFor.

Please help me to understand how can I bind individual elements so that if I click on one element's icon the action will be performed only on that item not to all elements which were generated by the ngFor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the reportCard (r) to your unpinCard function and set ifMinimized and isPinned on that card: `r['ifMinimized'] = !r['ifMinimized']`

Or remove the function and simple type it in the html:

```
(click)="r.ifMinimized = !r.ifMinimized"
*ngIf="!r.ifMinimized"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Its working now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: One issue I am facing.. If I go for function based approach then for the first time clicking on the icon the animation is not working but from second time its working. I have printed the r[ifMinimized] in console, first time it is coming undefined but from second time (click) it show in false or true and so on.  Can kindly you explain me a little why this is so?

Comment: Give the variable isPinned an initial value (unpin or pin)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.. I have initialized the variable in constructor, but still it is happening... 
 
        this.ifMinimized = false;
        this.isPinned = "pin";    -- the console.log is displaying undefined for the first time

Comment: You're setting the ifMinimized and isPinned GLOBAL variables. We just put those variables inside every reportCards object. Maybe that's the origin of your problem. you have to access the variable inside the objects, not the global one.

Comment: Hi Carsten, the Report Object is nothing but the json which contains the data of the individual reports coming from backend REST api. But in component.ts I have declared these two variables... initialised in constructor. Also the code is working as you suggested r.<variablename> Then how do I make them local to the object.. Sorry I am not getting you.

Comment: if you look at my answer you can see that we create a variable inside the *ngFor reportCard (r) by doing: r['ifMinimized'] = !r['ifMinimized']. This way we create a ifMinimized variable in the reportCard object and set it to it's inverse. since it's undefined at first, !undefined is then true. and after that it toggles true and false. you are using globally defined variables for individual objects...

Comment: Got it. So I have to initialize with true/false in DOM. Is it using...  r[isPinned] = 'pin', statement after ngFor? Its throwing error !. Sorry for this dont have much expertise in Angular